# Facebook unattended access for multiple accounts

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

My application will be used to read the walls of up to 20 Facebook pages and also to post and perform other authenticated activities on behalf of those pages.

Retrieving the wall posts is easily possible via the graph API.  However, posting and doing other things on behalf of each of these users is where my question lies.

A bit more background:

The app will have users who will drive the sending of messages.  These users will be happy to grant access to our app manually as a one off exercise, but  but they do not want to log in every time they run the app.

The question:

I want to collect the login/password details *once* during installation - and for the applications server to handle the token request, posting activities and other things thereafter in an 'unattended' manner.  Is this possible - and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the `manage_pages` permission. Then obtain a page access token by querying..

```
 [User ID]/accounts
```

After you obtain an access token, extend that access token forever via...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

*Note*: Extended access tokens only last forever for page access tokens. Other extended access tokens only last 60 days.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess this handles the posting to our own pages.  But occasionally, we need to post to a user's wall to say "your message / comment on our page has been read out on air".  Is this possible with the above?